# What's the short key to comment/uncomment several lines in zend studio?

Tags: zend-studio

Anyone knows this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't actually use Zend Studio, however it is based on the Eclipse platform.  For a default Eclipse install typically <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> is typically mapped to toggle comments.  I've also seen <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> mapped to comment and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> used to uncomment.

You can always check your key binding by going to Window->Preferences and selecting "Keys" under the "General" branch of settings.